# Horizontal Attendance Table - Automatically update percentages

Tags: excel

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XJCM.png)

As you can see from the picture, I want to make an attendance chart for my students that grows horizontally as the days go by. I'd like to count the number of A's, L's, and P's that appear as data on the right. Then, I can divide that by the total number of days to get a ratio.

I have the table setup to add another column each time data is entered. What I need help with is finding a way to reference just the data to the right of the names and not include the first 5 columns.

**What I've tried to access just the attendance data:**

I tried using structured references such as Table[@[Column6]:[Column8]]. However, this won't update automatically when new data is added to the right. It just stays on Column8.

I've tried using explicit cell references F3:ADDRESS(3, COLUMNS(Table)), but this would give me an error

I tried to concatenate the name of the last column Table[@[Column6]:[CONCAT("Column", TEXT(COLUMNS(Table), "0"))], but this didn't work either.

Any suggestions would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For Present Rate, you could try `COUNTIF(F3:J3,"P")/COUNTA(F3:J3)` and replace J3 with the last cell in the row. Eg. if the last day is 31, then the formula would be `COUNTIF(F3:AJ3,"P")/COUNTA(F3:AJ3)`.

Late Rate formula `=COUNTIF(F3:J3,"L")/COUNTA(F3:J3)`

Absent Rate formula `=COUNTIF(F3:J3,"A")/COUNTA(F3:J3)`

Note: These are all formulas for Student 1.

[Screenshot of Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3pIy.png)

Comment: You could use =COUNTIF(F3:XFD3,"P") etc. for the whole row - may slow it down a bit but not too much.

Comment: Hey Nishanth,

Thanks for the effort into solving the problem. Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for.

While your formula will give me the correct percentage, it won't update if I add more columns of data (e.g. more dates). This is why I wanted to construct a table to keep track of attendance, but if I have to keep updating the formulas each time, I'm afraid of making a mistake somewhere and forgetting to update it.

Basically, in your reference, I'd like a way to update J3 to always be the last column. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Tom,

Thank you. If I can't find a more efficient way I might go with that.

Comment: Actually I think it's pretty efficient because countif only uses the actual data range internally so not worth using a more complicated formula

Comment: Hey Jamey, as long as the 2nd row has the number of days, then try =COUNTIF(F3:J3,"P")/LOOKUP(2,1/(2:2<>0),$2:$2) . Hope it helps!